# Method references not working in Java stream filter

Tags: java, java-stream, method-reference

I have a list with some strings and I want to filter these list, but the methode reference ::startsWith is not working as I expect it.

```
private static final String KEY = "key=";

List<String> keyList = List.of("key=123", "value12", "value=34", "key=5678");

List<String> filtered = keyList.stream().filter(KEY::startsWith).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> filtered1 = keyList.stream().filter(e -> e.startsWith(KEY)).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<String> filtered2 = keyList.stream().filter("key="::startsWith).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Only filtered1 has the expected two entries, the other lists are empty. Why is KEY::startsWith not working as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it the wrong way round.

```
.filter(KEY::startsWith)
```

means the same as

```
.filter(k->KEY.startsWith(k))
```

This checks whether `KEY` starts with the element to filter.

but you want to check if the element to filter starts with key.

```
.filter(k->k.startsWith(KEY))
```

If you look at [the Java Language Specification, chapter 15.13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), you can see this:

> The target reference of an instance method (§15.12.4.1) may be provided by the method reference expression using an ExpressionName, a Primary, or super, or it may be provided later when the method is invoked. The immediately enclosing instance of a new inner class instance (§15.9.2) is provided by a lexically enclosing instance of this (§8.1.3).

This means that it will use the variable on the left side of the `::` operator as the object to call `startsWith`.

This is also explained in [the method references page of the Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html):

> **Reference to an Instance Method of an Arbitrary Object of a Particular Type**
> The following is an example of a reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type:
>
> ```java
> String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
>     "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
> Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
> ```
>
> The equivalent lambda expression for the method reference `String::compareToIgnoreCase` would have the formal parameter list (String a, String b), where a and b are arbitrary names used to better describe this example. The method reference would invoke the method `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

`KEY::startsWith` means:

```
x -> KEY.startsWith(x)
```

So you are checking if `key=` starts with `key=123` etc, which is the wrong way around. You should be checking whether `key=123` starts with `key=`. The same goes for `"key="::startsWith`.

You can't really use a method reference to `startsWith` here. **If** there is a method called something like `isStartOf` in `String`:

```
public boolean isStartOf(String other) {
    return other.startsWith(this);
}
```

then you could use `KEY::isStartOf`, but I don't think there is a method like that built in.

Comment: @user15358848 yeah, which is why I didn't suggest it.